# Can't get the correct balance of a token after I restart geth node within docker

Tags: go-ethereum

I use docker to build a private network, and then I issue a token and I can get the balance correctly. however, after I stop it then restart the geth node, I can't get the right balance of the token I issued before. but if I build the private network without docker, it works well, Details pls look at https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/18383

Comment: If you're not using persisted volume all your data will be wiped.

Comment: Thx, of cause I persisted the data. like this:     ```version: '3.6'
services:
  miner:
    image: ethereum/client-go
    container_name: miner
    volumes:
      - .:/ethconf
      - ~/ethereum_private_testnet:/root/.ethereum
    networks:
      - testnet
    ports:
      - "8545:8545"
    entrypoint: sh /ethconf/start_node.sh
volumes:
  ethereum_miner:
    driver: local

networks:
  testnet:
``` .   but it still doesn't work.